# "И что кто-то мог остаться и не уехать у нас такого просто не может быть"

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Интересно, как вы расставите знаки препинания в этом предложении?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

***И что кто-то мог остаться и не уехать... У нас такого просто не может быть!***

Comment: А вопросительную интонацию вы не рассматриваете? Напр.: И что, кто-то мог остаться и не уехать? У нас такого просто не может быть.

Comment: Серж, но я же не слышал, как эта фраза была произнесена! Предложил своё как вариант. А если была вопросительная интонация, то вполне можно использовать и предложенные Вами знаки.

Comment: Я тоже не слышал. Просто мне на ум пришла только вопросительная интонация. На другом форуме двое предложили использовать тире на месте вашего многоточия. Но если честно, я не понимаю повествовательную интонацию в данном предложении, поэтому было интересно услышать и мнение других.

Answer (score 1):

И что? Кто-то мог остаться и не уехать? У нас такого просто не может быть!
И что? Кто-то мог остаться?.. И не уехать? У нас такого просто не может быть.
И что кто-то мог остаться... и не уехать... У нас такого просто не может быть...
И — что? Кто-то мог остаться и не уехать? У нас такого просто не может быть.
И что кто-то мог остаться. И не уехать. У нас такого... Просто не может быть!..

Answer (score 1):

Предположительно, имелось в виду следующее:

*У нас не случается такого, что кто-то остается (не уезжает).*

По правилам нереальность ситуации должна быть передана с помощью слова *чтобы*, но в разговорной речи его заменили на *что*.

**И что(бы) кто-то мог остаться и не уехать, у нас такого просто не может быть!**

или

**И что(бы) кто-то мог остаться и не уехать — у нас такого просто не может быть!**

Answer (score 1):

**И чтобы кто-то мог остаться и не уехать ― у нас такого просто не может быть.**

Перед постановкой знаков препинания желательного определить **грамматику предложения,** ведь даже один и тот же смысл можно выразить в разных грамматических формах.

Итак, перед нами **СПП с придаточным местоименно-определительным и инверсией** придаточной и главной части.

***ТАКОГО*** ― субстантивированное местоимение в роли опорного (определяемого) слова, ***ЧТОБЫ*** ― союз, передающий  ирреальное значение, местоименно-союзная связь "такое ― чтобы".

**Тире** ставится в связи **с инверсией** и обозначает увеличенную  паузу.